# Why are all files incoming via FTP erased into empty files?

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, ftp

My FTP service is misbehaving.
Erasing all incoming files to empty (0 filesize)

I have been running FreeBSD 9.0 webserver, and finally thought I would upgrade.
I tried to to it using this command:

```
freebsd-update -r 10.3-RELEASE upgrade
```

The upgrade failed with error about being "unable to verify" something and "afraid" or something and exiting.

Now, since that event, I have the FTP problem. Can someone tell me about what is going on? (I have been using a custom port number, not 21)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to diagnose such vague problems over the Internet. Look at the system logs for clues. If that doesn't help (but it probably will), [trace](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?truss) the FTP server to see what it's doing — analyzing the trace is a lot more difficult than reading log messages though.

It's unlikely that the problem is related to the failed upgrade, but it is possible that the upgrade stopped at a bad point and left the system configuration in an unexpected state. You should complete the upgrade. If you need help with that, be sure to copy-paste the full sequence of commands that you ran and the full error messages.

I'll take a stab in the dark — but keep in mind that this is only a wild guess. The FTP protocol uses two ports: one for metadata (commands), and one for the file contents. If your firewall settings let the commands port through but not the file contents port, this might explain what you're seeing — the FTP server receives the command to upload a file, but then it doesn't receive any content because the connection is blocked. So check your firewall settings. And consider using SFTP rather than FTP: SFTP doesn't have this peculiarity of multiple ports and the reverse connections of FTP active mode.